# How to remove the whitespace at outer of the loop condition?

Tags: perl

My perl code

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my @a = <DATA>;
my %j = qw(aa AA bb BB cc CC dd DD ee EE ff FF gg GG hh HH ii II jj JJ kk KK ll LL);
my @vj = map+split,@a;
my @mkh;
foreach(@vj){
    my $k = $j{$_};
    my @ab =  split(' ',$k);
    push(@mkh,@ab);
}
print "@mkh";
__DATA__
jj dd ee aa ii hh kk ll gg bb cc  ff
```

How to print the output without whitespace at outside of the loop? Inside the loop condition print the output without spaces, But i expect which output is print outside of the loop how can i do?

Comment: You know that `@a = <DATA>` is reading in a single element `$a[0]`, and that element has a `\n` on the end? Why not use `$a = <DATA>` and then `chomp $a`. If you do that, you don't need `map`.

Answer (score 1):

It's just

```
print @mkh;
```

without quotes, if I understand your question right.

BTW, I'm still wondering about `map+split,@a`. I'd write `map split, @a;` or `map { split } @a;`. Why does the plus sign not break anything?

It seems that `+@foo` is the same array as `@foo`, but `-@foo` is the negative size of `@foo`. Funny.

Comment: Thank you sir, 'map split,@a' is behave like 'map+split,@a;'+ sign i used for differentiate the map and split function. I am just a beginner in perl.

Comment: Nice effort for a beginner :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you interpolate an array, the elements are separated by the `$"` global variable.

To avoid that behavior, just [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) the array directly.

```
 print @mkh;
```

This is documented in [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> - `$LIST_SEPARATOR`
> - `$"`
>
>   When an array or an array slice is interpolated into a double-quoted string or a similar context such as `/.../` , its elements are separated by this value. Default is a space. For example, this:
>
>   ```
>      print "The array is: @array\n";
>   ```
>
>   is equivalent to this:
>
>   ```
>      print "The array is: " . join($", @array) . "\n";
>   ```
>
>   Mnemonic: works in double-quoted context.

On a side note, perhaps you'd like to be introduced to the [`uc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/uc.html) and [`lc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lc.html) functions.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    s/\s//g;
    print uc, "\n";
}

__DATA__
jj dd ee aa ii hh kk ll gg bb cc  ff
```

Outputs:

```
JJDDEEAAIIHHKKLLGGBBCCFF
```

Comment: Although not putting the quotes around `@mkh` works. It doesn't resolve the issue of not having a `\n` on the end of the `print`. Unfortunately, adding `print @mkh . "\n";` prints out `12`. You need to either use `say` or `print join( "", @mkh ) . "\n";`

Comment: Or just use a comma `,` instead of concatenation `.` which forces a scalar context?